# arithmetic expression must use numeric argument

Tags: apex

This error is driving me crasy

```
arithmetic expression must use numeric argument

obj.Without_credit_time_off_amount__c =( (User.Salary__c)/30)*obj.Days__c;

Without_credit_time_off_amount__c currency type
Days__c formula field, number type
Salary__c is a currency type
```

I've tried to cast the `salary__c` value but in vain

Comment: Can you clearly explain your variable name and type again?

Comment: Without_credit_time_off_amount__c >>> currency type | 
Days__c >>>  formula field, number type |
Salary__c  >>>  currency type

Comment: Can you post your casting expression?

Comment: here you are : obj.Without_credit_time_off_amount__c = ((Decimal)(User.Salary__c)/30)*obj.Days__c;  But currency type is already known as a Decimal type on Apex

Comment: I think the problem is in the arithmetic operator / , x / Y. Divides x, an Integer or Double, by y, another Integer or Double. Note that if a double is used, the result is a Double.

Comment: Just a thought.. is User a variable? If it's used as the object name, it will return the string representation of the field name. Try doing a debug on all operands so you see what you get for each of them.

Comment: User is a standard object name and the Salary__c is his Custom field. 'm workin with eclipe and my code is dirty can upload it to the salesforce server. Okey 'll work directely on my salesforce session

Comment: Yes but I'm saying that User.salary__c will return the string "Salary__c" unless you have something like User user; somewhere upstream.

Comment: Why will it return string ?? I declared it as a currency !!! plz explain it furthermor

Comment: Just do System.debug(User.salary__c); in your code above so you see exactly what you get. Do the same for other values as well. If they are all numeric, forget about what I said. If instead of a number, you get "Salary__c", then you are not using the proper variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think zdropic has identified the problem. With no other variables involved:

```
User.Salary__c
```

is an `SObjectField` token and can't be used in an arithmetic expression. (Its purpose is to provide a compile-time checked token that represents a field of an `SObject`; it can be used with `SObject.get` and `SObject.put` and in describe calls.) If you have a variable called `User` (or `user` given the Apex compiler's case insensitivity) in scope, that would normally have precedence, but it is clearer to not user variable names that are identical to object type names.

There is no global `User` object, there is only a global `UserInfo` object. So I would expect code looking like this to work here:

```
User u = [select Salary__c from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
obj.Without_credit_time_off_amount__c = (u.Salary__c / 30) * obj.Days__c;
```

Comment: Awsomly working :) thank you Keith ! So you are telling me to manipulate my user fields I should use UserInfo, didnt know that! thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out something, is that I cant manipulate a custom field on user without inisialised it !!!! is there any other way to manipulate it without inisialised it?